# linq equals override

Tags: linq, equals

Can somebody help me to override equals operator in C# linq?

This is the problem:

```
var temp = 
from t1 in table1
join t2 in table2 on t1.column1 **equals** t2.column2
select t1.column4;
```

it is worth mentioning that `t1.column1` and `t2.column2` are actually some specific types. If anyone needs more information, please let me know.

Comment: Carefull with overriding such operators... you forgott to mention your problem. Are the columns a specific type or UDT?

Comment: Are you saying they're different types? Just cast them to the same matching type, e.g. "on (int?)t1.column1 equals (int?)t2.column2"

Answer (score 4):

Well, you haven't explained whether this is LINQ to Object, LINQ to SQL etc... but assuming it's LINQ to Objects, you just need to override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods in the types involved.

If it's LINQ to SQL, it's rather harder - you can't specify a custom comparison as far as I'm aware.

If you could give more details about what you're trying to achieve it would make it a lot easier to help you.